# Instrument still complain about memory leak after releasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have the following for creating and releasing objects, but instrument still complaining about the memory leak. All the possible leak objects have been released. I'm not sure whether the order of the releasing matters or not.

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    // drawing the gradiant from left to right and from green to yellow to red
    // the position of yellow should be
    UIColor *greenColor = [CNVColorUtils colorWithHexString:@"#09c961"];
    UIColor *redColor = [CNVColorUtils colorWithHexString:@"#ff3431"];
    UIColor *neutralColor = [CNVColorUtils colorWithHexString:@"#fff00c"];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat greenEnd = self.positivePercentage ?: kCNVSentimentsBarMinPersentage;
    CGFloat yellowEnd = greenEnd + self.neutralPercentage ?: kCNVSentimentsBarMinPersentage;

    CGFloat firstGradientStart = MAX(0, greenEnd - kCNVSentimentsBarTransactionPercentage);
    CGFloat firstGradientEnd = MIN(yellowEnd, greenEnd + kCNVSentimentsBarTransactionPercentage);

    CGFloat secondGradientStart = MAX(greenEnd, yellowEnd - kCNVSentimentsBarTransactionPercentage);
    CGFloat secondGradientEnd = MIN(1.0, yellowEnd + kCNVSentimentsBarTransactionPercentage);

    NSArray *colors = @[(id)greenColor.CGColor, (id)greenColor.CGColor, (id)neutralColor.CGColor, (id)neutralColor.CGColor, (id)redColor.CGColor,(id)redColor.CGColor];

    CGFloat locations[6] = {0.0, firstGradientStart, firstGradientEnd, secondGradientStart, secondGradientEnd, 1.0};

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)colors, locations);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0), CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame), 0.0), 0);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);

}
```

The instrument complains about the leak object is `CGGradient`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ARC?  Or manually releasing?  (If the latter, can you show where you're doing that?)

Comment: I'm using ARC, I believe

Comment: Thanks, I might check out how to use  static analyzer @Rob

Comment: if you are using arc then you don't need to allocate or remove memory, it's done for you.  But if you aren' then you need to release each thing, sort of like how in `C` coding you have to use `malloc` and `free`.  Anyway, @Rob is right that the static analyzer is often, so you should probably work with his suggestion(s) for now :D

Comment: As an aside, in the future, you can cut the Gordian knot and use a [`CAGradientLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer?language=objc), which gets you out of manually managing all of these CoreFoundation memory references. But if the above accurately represents the code that's leaking, it may be moot as I suspect the leak rests elsewhere, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Run the code through the static analyzer (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or “Analyze” on Xcode’s “Product” menu). It’s remarkably good at finding these sorts of issues. But I’m not seeing any obvious leak in the above code.

<strike>There is a problem here, though, that you are overreleasing `colorRef` because the `NSArray` and ARC should be managing that array for you. But that is an over-release, not a leak.</strike> [The offending piece of code that this referenced has been edited out of the question.]

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the code, and I retrieve the context using UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext, according to the create and get rule, we don't have to release it, right?

Comment: Correct. I've removed that portion of the answer now that you've updated the question, showing us how `context` was defined. You only need to manually release those items that you created with functions with either `Create` or `Copy` in the name.

Comment: Does the order of releasing matter? or is that any dependence I have to release one before another?

Comment: I don't believe the order matters (though as a matter of habit, I generally do it in the reverse order that they were created, effectively LIFO, last-in-first-out).

Comment: @KesongXie - I just ran the above code through Instruments Allocations/Leaks as well through the static analyzer (only replacing your `CNV` stuff with normal `UIColor` and `CGFloat` code) and saw no reported leaks. Is it possible that the view or view controller leaked (and thus everything associated with that view would have leaked)? (FYI, the debug memory graph feature is good at finding strong reference cycles and the like.) I'd suggest you create a stand-alone blank project that manifests the problem you describe, and then share that with us. We can't help until we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and I might try to trace down whether there is a leak of the view or view controller if that might lead to the instrument to complain about the `drawRect`